# How to reuse constants in the same config.js file

Tags: javascript, config

I am trying to create a config.js file, which should contains the constants for the other js files that I have.
I could not find any other information about that if it is possible to "reuse" the constants in the same config file.

For example:

const Config = {
   ROWS: 10,
   COLUMNS: ROWS,
};

Comment: how are you going to use it? is it the browser? node? etc.?

Answer (score 1):

```
const tableWidth = 10;

const config = {
  ROWS: tableWidth,
  COLUMNS: tableWidth,
};
```

But instead of doing it this way, I would find a better name for the constant and use it anywhere it needs to be used, rather than setting two constants to the same value.

```
const config = {
  TABLE_DIMENSION: 10,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to reuse a property during object definition which unfortunately is not possible. Although, you can reuse them like this.

```
const Config = { ROWS: 10 }
Config.COLUMNS = Config.ROWS
```